# Enter valid double input C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to get this correct for a while now. I finally gave up, I need help. So, what I'm trying to do is to get the user to provide me with valid double input with only one decimal point, e.g - "12.1". If a user enters 12.1.1 I want the program to start all over again till a valid double input is provided.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double ReadDouble(string prompt);

int main() {
    ReadDouble("Enter double: \n");

}

double ReadDouble(string prompt) {
    string input;
    bool done = false;
    do {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> input;
        done = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            int count = 0;
            if (isdigit(input[i]) == 0) {
                if (ispunct(input[i]) != 0) {
                    count++;
                    count > 1 ? done = false : done = true;
                } else {
                    done = false;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (done == false);

    double retVal = stod(input.c_str());
    cout << retVal << endl;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: What does your code do when you compile and run it? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what is the output? How does the actual output differ from what you want?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The program starts with "Enter double:", I enter: 12a. The program asks again for a double because this is not valid double input. I enter  "12.1.1" and I get 12.1 as an output. The program ends. This is where I want the program to notice this as an error and ask me again to enter double and not just expect 12.1.1 as 12.1.

Comment: I suggest you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your code. Following this advice will help you find where your code doesn't behave the way you want it to. Then if you still can't figure out how to fix it, you can provide more information in your question here to show us what the problem is.

Comment: A few style remarks: The return value of `ispunct` is int (beacuse it is from times in C when there was no bool), but it has boolean semantics. The idiomatic way to use it in an if clause would be `if( ispunct(c) ) {....}`. For proper booleans like `done` it is more elegant and imo better understandable because it resembles natural speach to write `if (done)` instead of the redundant `if(done == true)`. Oh, and though I have probably never used `ispunct` it appears to test for any punctuation, not just a dot.

Comment: Are you familiar with regex? I think it would be simpler than checking the characters by hand.

Comment: @BradyDean I'm not. I'm new to this language. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I found a solution. Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made some minor changes in your code, maybe it can meet your requirements.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double ReadDouble(string prompt);

int main() {
    ReadDouble("Enter double: \n");
}

double ReadDouble(string prompt) {
    string input;
    bool done = false;
    do {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> input;
        done = false;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

            if (isdigit(input[i]) == 0) {
                if (ispunct(input[i]) != 0) {
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                continue;   
        }
        count > 1 ? done = false : done = true;

    } while (done == false);

    double retVal = stod(input.c_str());
    cout << retVal << endl;
    return retVal;
}
```

If enter "12.1.1" and the program will ask you to reinput the double until the correct double entered, maybe like this:

```
Enter double:
12.1.1
Enter double:
12.1.33
Enter double:
12.1
12.1
press any key to continue. . .
```

Comment: What does your program output for "1!9"?

Comment: I appreciated, Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want to manually parse the user's input yourself, but using a regex simplifies the process. This matches any number of digits, optionally a period, then another optional digit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool ValidateDouble(const std::string& str) {
  const std::basic_regex dbl (R"(^\d+\.?\d?$)");
  return std::regex_match(str, dbl);
}

double ReadDouble(const std::string& prompt) {
  std::string input;
  bool match = false;

  do {
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    match = ValidateDouble(input);
  } while (!match);

  return std::stod(input);
}

int main() {
  double d = ReadDouble("Enter double: ");
  std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I appreciated! I found a solution!

Comment: @MartinEvtimov I think Peter was pointing out a bug in the code, might want to check over it again.